# C++ calls OpenCV in python with multithreading

Tags: python, c++, multithreading, opencv

C++ calls Python.(Python3.6+VS2012+opencv_python‑3.4.0‑cp36‑cp36m‑win_amd64)

I initialize Python in the main thread, and execute python statements in sub-thread.

I can normally call skimage, sklearn and numpy in any thread apart from **OpenCV**. When i use **OpenCV** in the sub-thread, the program will be stuck. But in the main thread, OpenCV can be used.
Here is my code.

```
#include "Python.h"
#include <process.h>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

unsigned int __stdcall TestThread(void*p)
{
    if (!Py_IsInitialized())
    {
        cout << "error" << endl;
    }
    PyRun_SimpleString("import cv2");
    PyRun_SimpleString("import numpy");
    PyRun_SimpleString("img_str = u'D:/rgb.bmp'");
    PyRun_SimpleString("imgInitial = cv2.imdecode(numpy.fromfile(img_str, dtype=numpy.uint8), -1)");
    PyRun_SimpleString("print(imgInitial.shape)");
    return 0;
}

void main()
{
    Py_Initialize();
    PyRun_SimpleString("import cv2");
    PyRun_SimpleString("import numpy");
    PyRun_SimpleString("img_str = u'D:/rgb.bmp'");
    PyRun_SimpleString("imgInitial = cv2.imdecode(numpy.fromfile(img_str, dtype=numpy.uint8), -1)");
    PyRun_SimpleString("print(imgInitial.shape)");   
    _beginthreadex(NULL, 0, TestThread, NULL, 0, NULL);
    while(1);
}
```